# Running binary with "./" from subprocess.run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having some trouble running some binaries with `subprocess.run`

I have a binary file at `/tools`, lets call the binary `program`. So I need to call `/tools/program`.

Every option I try, subprocess shows that the file does not exist. I have tried the following.

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TOOL_DIR = ROOT_DIR + '/tools/program'

# All of the following return error not found
program_subprocess = subprocess.run(['./'+TOOL_DIR])
program_subprocess = subprocess.run(['./"'+TOOL_DIR+'"'])
# Tried without the /, cause TOOL_DIR has a slash at the start
program_subprocess = subprocess.run(['.'+TOOL_DIR])
```

Any idea on how to run binaries with `subprocess.run` using `./`?

EDIT: Also tried

`subprocess.run([./\"+TOOL_DIR+'\"'])`

Comment: Why do you need the `./`?

Comment: It looks like you have an absolute path to the program.... just run `/tools/program`. The program doesn't seem like its relative to your current working directory so, `./` isn't the right thing to use.

Comment: Thats the only way I found how to run the binary im using, at least from the console. Its a `go` based binary

Comment: @tdelaney that was it! I usually check how programs run using cmd before I run the `subprocess` and the way they go is almost the same. Could you post as answer?

Comment: ``/somewhere/tools/program`` and ``./somewhere/tools/program`` are completely different paths, and there is a very high chance the latter does not exist. Just use the former without the ``.``, or use only ``./tools.program`` (without the root dir).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `subprocess` the operating system has to find the executable file somehow. Normally, executables are installed, can be found in `PATH` and you just use the program name - `subprocess.run(["program"])`.

In your case it looks like you know the absolute path to the executable, so you can use it - `subprocess.run(["/tools/program"])`. The downside is that your script can only be run on machines that have the binary in the /tools directory.